# Como imprimir la linea nro 10 despues de cada caracter especial '\x0c' que se encuentre en el archivo con Python

Tags: python

Buenas tengo el siguiente texto

```
'\x0c' texto largo largo
10 lineas despues 
900900
texto largo texto largo
'\x0c' texto largo largo
10 lineas despues 
900901
texto largo texto largo
'\x0c' texto largo largo
10 lineas despues 
900906
texto largo texto largo
```

Necesito imprimir esos números que se encuentran 10 lineas por debajo del **'\x0c'** siempre

lo que hacia hasta ahora imprimir directo el numero de linea pero me es imposible saber todos

```
with open("archivolargo.txt") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i == 10:
            print line[0:5]
        if i == 180:
            print line[0:5]
        if i == 297:
            print line[0:5]
```

gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre ir contando las líneas del fichero, y reiniciar ese contador cada vez que se encuentra una línea que comienza por `\x0c`.

Cuando el contador vale 10, se imprime el número en cuestión.

Si el fichero no comienza por `\x0c` hay que tomar una precaución especial para evitar imprimir la línea 10 del fichero. Lo más sencillo es iniciar el contador de líneas con 11 para que eso no pueda ocurrir.

```
c = 11

for linea in fichero:
  c+=1
  if c == 10:
    print linea[0:5]
  if linea.startswith("\x0c"):
    c=0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
contador = 0
caracter_encontrado = False
archivo = open("archivo.txt")
valores = []

for linea in archivo:
    if(linea.find("\\x0c") != -1):
        caracter_encontrado = True 
    if(caracter_encontrado):
        contador += 1
        if(contador == 12):
            valores.append(linea)
            caracter_encontrado = False
            contador = 0

archivo.close()

print("\n".join(valores))
```